# Como verifico se um serviço do windows está instalado, se estiver iniciar o serviço via arquivo batch

Tags: windows, batch

Preciso executar um serviço para alguns processos, mas primeiro precisava verificar se o serviço está instalado.

Os comandos que eu uso para instalar e desinstalar são os seguintes:

```
%DIRServico%\SERVICO.EXE /INSTALL
%DIRServico%\SERVICO.EXE /UNINSTALL
```

Se eu tentar instalar ele mesmo já instalado, ele da um erro e eu não queria que aparecesse, então queria que o próprio arquivo bat conseguisse verificar se o serviço está instalado.

Verificar se está rodando, parado eu já tenho os comandos.

```
NET START | FINDSTR "Servico"

if %ERRORLEVEL% == 1 goto stopped
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 goto started
echo comando desconhecido
goto end    
:started
NET STOP Servico
goto end
:stopped
NET START Servico
goto end
:end
```

Se alguém tiver uma ideia de como resolver eu agradeço.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O comando `SC QUERY` exibe informações sobre um determinado serviço, mostra o tipo, estado, etc.

Caso o nome do serviço passado como parâmetro não esteja instalado será apresentado o código de erro 1060, a partir daí podemos utilizar esse código de erro para fazer a verificação.

Adapte ao seu código:

```
@echo off

rem Nome do seu serviço:
set ServiceName=Servico

SC QUERY %ServiceName% > NUL
IF ERRORLEVEL 1060 GOTO nao

rem Comandos para rodar caso o serviço esteja instalado:
ECHO Servico instalado!
GOTO fim

:nao
rem Comandos para rodar caso o serviço não esteja instalado:
ECHO Servico nao instalado!


:fim
pause
```

Para mais informações: https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dd228922(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Deu certo, valeu!

Answer (score 0):

Abaixo segue uma sugestão utilizando o programa nativo `sc`, utilizado para a comunicação com o Gerenciador de Serviços do Windows.

```
@echo off
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set SERVICE_NAME=myservice
rem Verifica se o serviço está rodando
    echo Verificando se o %SERVICE_NAME% está instalado
    sc query %SERVICE_NAME% | find /i "%SERVICE_NAME%"
rem Se existe o serviço
    if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" (
       goto :Fim
    )
    echo Instalando o serviço %SERVICE_NAME%
    sc create %SERVICE_NAME% start= auto binPath= "C:\mylocation\%SERVICE_NAME%" DisplayName= "%SERVICE_NAME%"
rem Inicia o serviço
    echo Iniciando o serviço %SERVICE_NAME%
    sc start %SERVICE_NAME%
    goto :Fim
rem
rem Finalização
:Fim
    endLocal
```

Comment: Valeu pela sugestão foi de grande ajuda. Obrigado!